# Compress an image by its size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to compress an image by its size using PHP? I mean I let the user enter the size of the image in KB and they get the image in that size.

Comment: Don't think so. The filesize depends on the amount of compression, and there's no rule to know which compression level will give your desired filesize (unless trying different levels, which is quite time-consuming and not really smart)

Comment: @Pierre - ...and that would only work on some file types and up to a certain level.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson of course, forgot to say that. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really make sense in exact KB. Why would you want that? It could be, however, reasonable to offer size ranges, e.g. 50-300KB, 500KB-1MB, etc. That way you could have fixed _dimensions_ to resize to while staying within the desired range, instead of trying to guess exact pixel dimensions by given image size.

Comment: It is more efficient to do it the other way around: Let user choose a compression ratio and tell what the file size would be, when it is used. You still have to perform the compression in the background, but only once, and if the user accepts, you have already done the compression.

Comment: it's possible with riot free image optimizer for windows

Comment: Of course that is possible, you just have to write the logic yourself. You can things like: first scaling resolution down to what you think will work good and is still within acceptable (minimal) range. If still to large, use a more aggressive compression level/lower quality until you get it down to the size you want it. Something like that. People here can comment on why you want that or if it is a smart thing to do, but if you have a requirement for it, than yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could compress the image of sorts by recreating the image with new dimensions.

```
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_name_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg' || $ext=='JPG' || $ext=='JPEG')
{
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_name_tmp);
}
else if($ext=="png" || $ext=="PNG")
{
$src = imagecreatefrompng($image_name_tmp);
}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($image_name_tmp);
}


list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_name_tmp);

$n_width = 320;
$n_height = ($height / $width) * $n_width;

$temp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
imagecopyresampled($temp_image, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($temp_image, $target, 100);
```